# Exact Target : REST API. Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I am sending exact target Triggered send email in salesforce.

How can we add an Attachment to the mail we are sending through exact target.

Thanks,

Comment: can you share your code once.

Answer (score 1):

In order to attach a file to an email, AMPScript needs to be included in the email which calls the AttachFile() function:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_attachments/

The file can exist on an FTP site, in your ExactTarget Porfolio, or any HTTP URL.